# Android app with remote server back-end?

Tags: android, sql, database, remote-server

I am creating an android application which allows the user to enter data into the table and retrieve existing data from it in order to generate reports.
What is the best option for back-end database? Also what tools and platforms would I require to integrate the front end android app with the back-end?

The back-end is a data-base on remote server. The android device communicates with the back-end using Wifi and all the record updation is done using Wifi as mode of communication.

Answer (score 0):

Based on application I developing right now the easiest way to perform client-server communication between a mobile app and a back-end server is using `JSON` objects to pass data. as they are very lightweight and can be transferred more quickly the `XML` objects.

Comment: I actually tried using myPhp and WAMP-server to store data, but whenever I add records it's not being updated in the database. So, after a lot of effort I am moving on to other back-end options.

Answer (score 0):

while i agree with the previous two answers, communication is best left in JSON format, the back-end database can be mysql or sqlite depending on the size, and the options available on the server.

you can implement the request handling in python, php, perl or write a custom app that uses sockets.

php is probably the easiest to implement a basic server functionality while python would be the fastest of the scripting languages

mysql would require some setup and configuration while sqlite doesn't need anything, you just open a .db file and run SQL queries.

Comment: Isn't SQLite only suitable for local storage of data i.e storing it on the android device? Also, when creating or updating tables in SQLite using the app, viewing the actually table or the file is not possible (unless you view it through the app itself). So viewing the changes or making modifications is a problem.

Comment: it can be used for local storage on android but you can use sqlite on a server as well. what do you mean by actually viewing table or the file? if you mean to view the table data, it's also impossible in mysql, the database files are not stored in plain text. both can be viewed through php-based or standalone apps (e.g. Liya, sqlite-manager, phpsqlite manager)